# strcmp giving segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers

this is my code giving segmentation fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char *get;
    scanf("%s", get);
    int k = strcmp("sachin", get);
    printf("%d", k);
}
```

thanks for any help;

Comment: Is the `C++` tag here a mistake? And if not, then you have much bigger problems.

Comment: @BoBTFish sorry for c++ tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char *get;
```

The above statement defines `get` to be a pointer to a character. It can store the address of an object of type `char`, not a character itself. The problem is with both `scanf` and `strcmp` call. You need to define an array of characters to store the input string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    // assuming max string length 40
    // +1 for the terminating null byte added by scanf

    char get[40+1];

    // "%40s" means write at most 40 characters
    // into the buffer get and then add the null byte
    // at the end. This is to guard against buffer overrun by
    // scanf in case the input string is too large for get to store

    scanf("%40s", get);
    int k = strcmp("sachin", get);
    printf("%d", k);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to allocate memory for the pointer `get`.

Or use a char array:

```
char   get[MAX_SIZE];
scanf("%s",get);
```

When you declare a pointer, it is not pointing to any memory address. You have to explicitly allocate memory for that pointer by `malloc` (c-style) or `new` (c++ style).

You will also need to manage the clean operation yourself by `free` / `delete` respectively.

Comment: i do not understand why i have to allocate memory it is already allocated when i declare it;

Comment: @SachinSetiya if you declare something memory is only allocated for the declared object itself - in this case the pointer.

Comment: @SachinSetiya No. while declaration you are just specifying that the pointer can point to a char. It does not start pointing immediately.

Comment: thank you sir i under stand  the  way but is there any way to get variable length string which does not have maximum length

Answer (score 0):

of sure you get a segment fault.
you told your computer to write user input to uninitialized pointer.

```
char   *get; // just a pointer that may wildly points anywhere
scanf("%s",get);
```

define get to be some char array

```
char get[SOME_LARGE_CONSTANTS_THAT_CLEARLY_IS_LARGER_THAN_YOUR_USER_INPUT];
```

Comment: i do not want spoil space by using a fixed array so used char *

Comment: @SachinSetiya that is not possible! your pointer does not point to any buffer! you have to allocate sufficient memory where the input routine may write to.